# Why numpy array doesn't change float to int?

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

```py
[row, col] = org_I.shape
[row, col] = np.array([row, col], dtype=np.int)/2
m = np.zeros((row,col))
```

I want to get matrix `[row/2, col/2]`, so did it.
However, it occurred error when i make zeros matrix using `[row, col]`.

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division by 2 converts the array back to being of `dtype = np.float64`. Use integer division instead:

```
np.array([row, col]) // 2
```

You don't even need to specify the `dtype` of the array since `row` and `col` are the result of `.shape` and will be ints.

Answer (score 0):

Since `row` and `col` were originally `ints`, dividing them by 2 in the following code

```
[row, col] = np.array([row, col], dtype=np.int)/2
```

The `row` and `val` now become floats, with decimal `.5` due to the division.

You could solve the problem by removing the decimal (integer division):

```
[row, col] = np.array([row, col], dtype=np.int)//2
```

Note that `//` was used instead of `/`